# Connect one USB storage to two ports for more data load capacity

Tags: usb, port, usb-storage, data-transfer

Hi everyone here is a **tricky** question...
I have two USB 2 ports on my laptop and an ADATA external storage, I wonder is there any way to connect one USB device(my storage) to two USB ports for more data transfer rate?? like every USB 2 has 480 Mbps in that way we have 960 Mbps data transfer speed...
*I thought there might be a solution like what "Internet Download manager" does in downloading the data in different parts and build a single file after the download is finished*, **can we transfer data from a single USB device using two different ports and double the transfer speed, or not??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB forms a hierarchical tree - every endpoint can only have one location in it. This implies, that your storage can only appear once in this tree - which in turn makes it impossible to connect it twice.

In early days of USB storage there existed dual-controller USB enclosures, that actually exposed two storage class endpoints - those were intended to be plugged into two clustered hosts but could be used on a single host via multipathing. Your ADATA device is most likely not such an exotic fish.

Answer (score 1):

No. USB stands for universal SERIAL bus - you can't practically split this up without custom hardware and drivers. You would find it cheaper and easier to get 2 USB SSD's and then use software to RAID them, although you may run into reliability issues with RAID on removable disks.

Comment: With USB 2.0 going for SSDs will be pointless, HDDs should easily saturate the bandwidth.

Comment: @gronostaj I believe that is false on 2 counts - SSDs have much,much lower seek times / (greater IOPS) so they would be more responsive then HDD and ssds have no moving parts so they are way more durable (including knock/drop resistant) then HDD. It us true that USB2 will be a bottleneck for raw harddrive thoughput) I do note that the OP is using SSD.